# shifting array element one by one

Tags: c, arrays

I got a homework question. I'm so close to complete program. I'm having trouble about one thing. This is the question:

> Write a C program that generates and displays a character array of size 10 consisting of
>   random English lower-case letters. The program then asks the user how many times the array
>   will be right-shifted and displays the right shifted array at each right-shifting step. A sample
>   program execution output is given below. ( Hint: Use the ASCII codes of the English lower-case
>   letters which are 97, 98, ... 122 for a, b, ..., z, respectively, to generate the character array).

This is my code:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print_string (char *string){
 int i;
 for (i=0 ; i < 10 ; i ++){
    printf("%c ", string[i]);
    if (i == 9)
     printf("\n");
  }

} 
void random_string(char *string, unsigned length)
{
  /* Seed number for rand() */
  srand((unsigned int) time(0) + getpid());

  /* ASCII characters 97 to 122 */
  int i;  
  for (i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
      string[i] = (rand() % 26)+ 97;
    }

  string[i] = '\0';  
}

void reverse_string(char* str, int left, int right) {
  char* p1 = str + left;
  char* p2 = str + right;
  while (p1 < p2) {
    char temp = *p1;
    *p1 = *p2;
    *p2 = temp;
    p1++;
    p2--;

  }
}

void rotate(char* str, int k, int n) {

  reverse_string(str, 0, n-1);
  reverse_string(str, 0, k-1);
  reverse_string(str, k, n-1);

}

int main(void)
{
  char s[11];
  int i,shiftNum;

  random_string(s, 11);
  printf("Randomly constructed array is :\n");

  print_string(s);

  printf("Enter how many times array will be shifted: ");
  scanf("%d",&shiftNum);

  rotate(s,shiftNum,11);
  print_string(s);

}
```

What's wrong with this code? When I execute it with 1, I couldn't get the first reverse correctly and I want to display all shifting steps.

Comment: You have Undefined Behaviour as you set `\0` in `s[11]` which is an invalid location. Also,`print_string()` doesn't print the first character of `s`

Comment: yes u are right i was trying something i forgot change it before asking it here thank u

Comment: Nit pick: "English lower-case letters" are those that are used in the English writing system, which includes accents, ligatures, etc. You could call 'a'..'z' the lower case letters from the English alphabet or, in more CS terms, [Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) small letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start, it is atrocious that your lecturer/professor is telling you to use 97..122. C does not require that ASCII be the character set on every system, so this code is entirely non-portable, yet if you look at the history as far as Unix is concerned C is supposed to be a portable programming language. If you want to write this in a portable way, you need to store the characters in an array and select from that array:

```
char lowercase[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
string[i] = lowercase[rand() % (sizeof lowercase - 1)];
```

---

Now that we've covered that pedantic detail, [Cool Guy indicated in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27427532/shifting-array-element-one-by-one#comment43296748_27427532) that this line of code is erroneous: `string[i] = '\0';`. He's correct about that.

---

This should also performed within `main`, not within `random_string`: `srand((unsigned int) time(0) + getpid());`. The reason is that calling `random_string` multiple times in the same second would result in the same "random string", which is very uncool.

---

`scanf("%d",&shiftNum);` can't guarantee success (that the user will input numeric data), and so can't guarantee that `shiftNum` will contain a sane value. You need to check the return value. For example:

```
if (scanf("%d", &shiftNum) != 1) {
    puts("Invalid shift count!\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

You should probably also consider using an unsigned type for `shiftNum` (and this will cause the corresponding format spec `%d` to change to something else, such as `%u` for `unsigned int`).

---

One more important task before I finish this task: You need to modify `rotate` to handle an input of 0 correctly, since some users might want to rotate/shift 0 times (as an alternative to not rotating/shifting at all). I'm confident that this should be an easy task for you.